# Is the image of a set under a class function a set?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Proposition 1.3.2 in *Handbook of Categorical Algebra Volume I* states that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a small category and $\mathcal{D}$ is a category, then the functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$ and their natural transformations form a category.

I am trying to show this. I believe I need to show that there exists a class $A$ such that $F \in A$ iff $F$ is a functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{D}$. I think this more or less reduces to showing the following statement:

Let $A$, $B$ be classes and $f:A \rightarrow B$ a class function. If $A$ is a set, then $f(A)$ is a set.

How can I show this statement is true?

Comment: I don't know what a set and a class really are, because I've never studied set theory. In my experience with category theory, we use the notion of Grothendieck universe to say what a small set is. With this notion, we have the proposition that if $x$ is small, any set in bijection with a subset of $x$ is also small. This implies your result because $f(A)$ is isomorphic to a subset of $A$, by the axiom of choice (equivalent to all surjections have a section).

Comment: Yes. This is the axiom of replacement.

Comment: @ZhenLin Thank you! The book doesn't seem to list the usual axioms of set theory, so I think I had better get a reference for those since evidently they are assumed.